# How to know which protocol a socket is using?

Tags: sockets

For socket() on Linux:

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

If I use the following lines to create a socket:

```
struct protoent *p = getprotobyname("tcp");
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, p->p_proto);
```

And later in somewhere I want to know what protocol the socket (fd) is using, that is, I want the answer is "tcp" or its protocol number 6. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't SOCK_STREAM imply TCP? Isn't the third option usually zero?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I'm not sure, there can be multiple protocols for AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM, for example, sctp can be another protocol.

Comment: I see. There is an SO_TYPE option to `getsockopt()`, but that returns the value of the second argument, SOCK_STREAM in this case.

Comment: Check the `ioctl`s, perhaps there's something. The workaround is trivial, create a lookup table for you sockets..

Answer (score 0):

```
SO_PROTOCOL (since Linux 2.6.32)
              Retrieves the socket protocol as an integer, returning a
              value such as IPPROTO_SCTP.  See socket(2) for details.
              This socket option is read-only.
```